# 'Help determine' vs 'help in determining'

Tags: verbs, prepositions, tenses, verb-agreement

I'm not a native English speaker and I'm having trouble understanding the usage of a preposition in the following example

- *These models can help regulate and determine pattern formation*
- *These models can help in regulating and determining pattern formation*

Are these equivalent? If not, what is the difference?

In the case of the first example, is it also correct to omit the "in" preposition, and simply write

- *These models can help regulating and determining pattern formation*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equivalent and better to retain the "in" in the second sentence.